# Cannot access NPM environment variables

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, command-line-interface

In my package.json I have set a config variable called "foo" to "bar", and I am calling that variable with an NPM script.

```
"config": {
    "foo": "bar"
    },
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo $npm_package_config_foo"
    }
```

Running `npm run test` should output `bar`, but it doesn't.

I suspect that I have a general issue accessing environmental variables. As an example, I can use uglifyjs from NPM scripts but not from the command line.

Running `printenv` from the command line doesn't show up any of the NPM variables that one would expect.

Setup: OSX 10.11.6, NPM 2.15.11, Node 6.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

1. Set `foo` using `npm config set foo bar`
2. Removed the config object from my package.json.
3. Change `$npm_package_config_foo` to `$npm_config_foo` in the NPM `scripts` properties

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying is wrong: node environment variables are only accessible using process global variable in a node process, not system-wide. So to achieve what you want you have to do is make following changes.

**package.json**

```
"config": {
    "foo": "bar"
    },
"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./app.js"
    }
```

**app.js**

```
console.log(process.env.npm_package_config_foo);
```

you can find more information [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#configuration)

Comment: It's not correct that "node environment variables are only accessible using process global variable in a node process" —  try putting `"test":"echo $npm_package_name"` in `scripts`, it works