# How can a bash script in an NPM module access its NPM environment variables?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, package.json, environment

I need to access npm environment variables of a submodule in a bash script that is running within it, when it is called from a parent NPM module.

Project pseudo-structure:

```
Parent NPM Project
│
├── node_modules
│   │
│   ├── npm-submodule
│   │   │
│   │   ├── bash-script.sh
│   │   │
│   │   └── package.json
│   .   
│     
├── package.json
│      
.
```

Parent NPM Project — `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "parent-project",
  "scripts": {
    "get-package-name": "echo $npm_package_name",
    "get-submodule-name": "npm-submodule"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-submodule": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

NPM submodule — `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "npm-submodule",
  "bin": "./bash-script.sh",
  "scripts": {
    "get-package-name": "echo $npm_package_name"
  }
}
```

NPM submodule — `bash-script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run get-package-name
```

**The Problem**

From the parent module, when I run `npm run get-package-name`, predictably `parent-project` is returned.

When I run `npm run get-submodule-name`, nothing is returned — it looks like the npm environment variables for the submodule aren't populated within the submodule when it is being called in this way.

In a **bash-based context**, how can a submodule access it's own NPM environment values, or failing that, read them directly from `package.json`?

Comment: I've seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587216/2876202, but the answer is wrong: "..node environment variables are only accessible using process global variable in a node process, not system-wide", clearly the node environment is accessible within run-scripts of the parent module's `package.json` — hoping for a solution 

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I came up with that works is to grab the folder that the bash script is in, and do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MODULE_DIR=$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")
cd "$MODULE_DIR" && npm run get-package-name -s
```

I tested it with `npm link` and it works globally within any other NPM project, but am still interested in other solutions.